# How can I efficiently pass JSON data from a PostgreSQL jsonb field to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, postgresql

I am looking for a smart solution to process some JSON data from a postgresql database in Javascript. I understand that I need to read the database via php and pass the data as an array to Javascript.

Normaly you would do something like this:

```
<?php
$phpArray = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
$jsonString = json_encode($phpArray);
?>

<script>
var jsonString = '<?php echo $jsonString ?>';
var jsArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
</script>
```

But my data is already stored in JSON format in a postgresql jsonb field. So I hope there is a way to pass the array more effectively so the PC doesn't have to iterate the same data twice.

```
root@monitor:~ $ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \c monitor
monitor=# SELECT * FROM "drone001";

id |                                             data
---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | {"RX": 13.7, "Speed": 10.1, "Azimuth": 897, "Heading": 125, "DateTime": "2023-03-19 04:14:49"}
 2 | {"RX": 13.4, "Speed": 10.2, "Azimuth": 896, "Heading": 125, "DateTime": "2023-03-19 04:14:47"}
 3 | {"RX": 13.3, "Speed": 10.1, "Azimuth": 896, "Heading": 125, "DateTime": "2023-03-19 04:14:45"}
 4 | {"RX": 13.7, "Speed": 10.1, "Azimuth": 896, "Heading": 127, "DateTime": "2023-03-19 04:14:43"}
 5 | {"RX": 13.1, "Speed": 10.1, "Azimuth": 896, "Heading": 125, "DateTime": "2023-03-19 04:14:41"}
[...]
```

this code does not work, but should show approximately what I have in mind.

```
<?php
  require_once 'pgsql.php';

  $db = new database();
  $res = $db->select('drone001');
  $jsondata = array();
  while ($ds = pg_fetch_object($res)) {
    $jsondata[] = $ds->data;
  }
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsondata ?>');
  console.log(jsArray);
</script>
```

It would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel a little stupid today. I found the solution, instead of creating a new array, I just need to join all the strings together.

```
<?php
  require_once 'pgsql.php';

  $db = new database();
  $res = $db->select('drone001');
  while ($ds = pg_fetch_object($res)) {
    $jsondata .= $ds->data . ",";
  }
  $jsondata = "[" . rtrim($jsondata, ",") . "]";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsondata ?>');
  console.log(jsArray);
</script>
```

Comment: Might be better to consider getting the data via a AJAX call

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit on this? is an ajax call faster? the log data at hand is relatively static and is updated hourly in the database.

Comment: Not faster, but more flexible and a better way of getting data to and from a web page without refreshing the page